# Does Baba Yaga drink blue rose tea to reverse ageing?

Tags: slavic, baba-yaga

Is the fact that Baba Yaga ages with each question asked and drinks blue rose tea to reverse ageing from Russian folklore or is it something the internet came up with?

I've heard several mentions it but can't find which story this information came from.

If you know any Russian folklore about blue roses, that be a big help too. I came across a story about an enchantress who could only be killed by finding a blue rose bush in a lake, but am finding it very difficult finding the title of the story.

Comment: There is a [discussion on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ABlue_rose#Blue_Rose_and_Baba_Yaga) that points to this being inspired by a computer game in the 90s that featured a Baba Yaga NPC, but that's far from confirmation. Hopefully, we can do better. Welcome to the site.

Comment: @yannis Drat. This might have answered [the blue chicken question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/43217/why-would-chickens-be-blue-in-the-soviet-union) over at History SE.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in the [Blue Rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Rose_(art_group)) group of symbolist painters in Moscow in 1906-1908. They took their name from the novel fragment *Heinrich von Ofterdingen* (1800) by the German poet Novalis. The novel contains the symbol of the "[blue flower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_flower)" (in German, *Blaue Blume*) that became inspirational for the Romantic movement, symbolising love, hope, beauty, the unreachable.